# 4k Display Limited to 30hz MacOS. SwitchResX LG 32UD59

Tags: display

I'm using SwitchResX to use a custom resolution of 3840 x 2160. But it's capped it at 30hz. Whereas if I switch to 2560 x 1440 I'm able to use 60Hz.

I have purchased SwitchResX but I'm unable to create a custom setting to enable 60hz. I keep getting "Not activated - Invalid"
What do I need to do to find out the correct setting for 60hz use on this monitor. 
LG 32UD59

I have a 2015 MacBook Pro, Im using a DP1.2 cable and it fully supports 60hz, I am able to use it on Bootcamp @ 60hz, but not MacOS

Comment: Just a thought here but perhaps the Mac does not support that refresh rate on those monitors at that resolution. Check the specs on your Mac and for actual help, post the make/model of Mac in your original question.

Comment: I have a 2015 MacBook Pro, Im using a DP1.2 cable and it fully supports 60hz, I am able to use it on Bootcamp @ 60hz, but not MacOS.

Comment: As far as I know, 4K 60hz is supported for MacBooks Pro from late 2013 ones.